# Hide page footer in RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I have a report where I need to print a footer only on the last page.
In order to doing so, I'm using a `Rectangle` in the footer area with this formula:

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,false,true)
```

Using this method, the footer is printed only in the last page, but in all the other pages, I have a lot of white space where the footer is supposed to be.
I think the problem is I change visibility only on the `Rectangle` object.
Is there a way to hide all the footer based on a condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can put that rectangle below the table itself rather than putting it in the footer then it will come only in the last page

Comment: Yes, but what i'm trying to do is putting it in the bottom of the last page. In the end I just end up using Crystal Report that use Report Footer to this automatically.